# jQuery Validation Plugin not Working With Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate, jquery-forms-plugin

I have found jQuery ajax script to upload file to the specific directory on my project folder. Now I am trying to validating fields using with [jQuery validation plugins](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Everything is working perfect but I have to submit 2 times for submit data. I am not able to send data with Ajax on 1 time when user submit the form. If I will click 2 time then it works which is not right. I don't know why it is not working on 1 time.

Can you please check my code and help me to fix this issue. I will appreciate you If you help me :)

Thanks.

**index.php**

```
<div id="content" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <div style="height:80%;width:97%;border:2px solid black;padding:10px 8px;">
        <form action="upload.php" method="POST" id="uploadform">
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
            <input type="file" name="file"/>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Upload"/>

            <div id="loader" style="display:none;">
                <center><img src="load.gif" /></center>
            </div>
            <div>
                Message : <div id="onsuccessmsg" style="border:5px solid #CCC;padding:15px;"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#uploadform").validate({
            rules: {
                "username": {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                "username": {
                    required: "Please, enter a name"
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo

                $("#uploadform").on('submit',function(){
                    $("#loader").show();
                        var options={
                        url : $(this).attr("action"),
                        success : onsuccess
                    };
                    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
                    return false;
                });

                function onsuccess(response,status){
                    $("#loader").hide();
                    $("#onsuccessmsg").html("Status :<b>"+status+'</b><br><br>Response Data :<div id="msg" style="border:5px solid #CCC;padding:15px;">'+response+'</div>');
                }

                return false; // for demo
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
    function getExtension($str){
        $i=strrpos($str,".");
        if(!$i){
            return"";
        }
        $l=strlen($str)-$i;$ext=substr($str,$i+1,$l);return $ext;
    }
    $formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp", "jpeg", "PNG", "JPG", "JPEG", "GIF", "BMP");

    if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $tmp  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        if(strlen($name)){
            $ext = getExtension($name);
            if(in_array($ext,$formats)){
                if($size<(1024*1024)){
                    $imgn = time().".".$ext;
                        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, "./uploads/".$imgn)){
                            echo "File Name : ".$_FILES['file']['name'];
                            echo "<br/>File Temporary Location : ".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                            echo "<br/>File Size : ".$_FILES['file']['size'];
                            echo "<br/>File Type : ".$_FILES['file']['type'];
                            echo "<br/>Image : <img style='margin-left:10px;' src='uploads/".$imgn."'>";
                        }else{
                            echo "Uploading Failed.";
                        }
                }else{
                    echo "Image File Size Max 1 MB";
                }
            }else{
                echo "Invalid Image file format.";
            }
        }else{
            echo "Please select an image.";
            exit;
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
submitHandler: function (form) { 
    $("#uploadform").on('submit',function(){  // <-  GET RID OF THIS
        $("#submit").click();                 // <-  WHAT IS THIS??
        $("#loader").show();
        var options={
            url : $(this).attr("action"),
            success : onsuccess
        };
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); // initialize Forms plugin… can't be here
        return false;
    });

    function onsuccess(response,status){
        $("#loader").hide();
        $("#onsuccessmsg").html("Status :<b>"+status+'</b><br><br>Response Data :<div id="msg" style="border:5px solid #CCC;padding:15px;">'+response+'</div>');
    }
return false;
}
```

Your code is failing because you've used a jQuery `submit` handler inside of the plugin's `submitHandler` callback function.  That sounds funny, doesn't it?

The plugin's `submitHandler` only fires when the submit button is clicked AND only when the form is valid.  (The plugin is *automatically* handling the submit/click)  Therefore, there is no need for another `submit` handler inside of this.  I also don't know why you're calling the `click()` event of the submit button inside of the `submit` handler… makes no sense.

Something like this is a lot closer to working code…

```
submitHandler: function (form) { 
    // all of your ajax stuff in here, no submit or click handlers needed
    return false;
}
```

---

Also, `.ajaxSubmit(options)` is the initialization of the Forms plugin.  Therefore this is why you need to click twice.  The first click initializes the Forms plugin.  The second click submits the form since the plugin is finally ready.  You cannot put `.ajaxSubmit()` inside of the jQuery Validate plugin's `submitHandler` callback.

Comment: Hi that unnecessarily code I removed now. Sorry for that.

Comment: So can you help me how to fix that :) plz

Comment: If I will remove `$("#uploadform").on('submit',function(){` this part the code will not work. I have tried that. Still I wrong but where don't know.

Comment: @lumos, try using [jQuery Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) by itself without the Forms plugin.  Put it inside the `submitHandler` like I've shown.  Once you get it working, you can build it back up from there.

Comment: @lumos, did you do what I suggested in that last comment?  I can't help if you don't communicate.